# How can I determine using ODBC APIs what an ALTER TABLE query supports

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, odbc

### These are the queries to add new columns to an existing table in different DBMS:

```
SQL Server:
ALTER TABLE [Table1] ADD [NewColumn1] float NULL, [NewColumn2] float NULL

Oracle (notice the parentheses):
ALTER TABLE "Table1" ADD ("NewColumn1" BINARY_DOUBLE NULL, "NewColumn2" BINARY_DOUBLE NULL)
```

1. How can I determine using ODBC APIs whether the columns to be added need to be enclosed in a set of parentheses or not?

### These are the queries to modify the existing columns in different DBMS:

```
SQL Server:
ALTER TABLE [Table1] ALTER COLUMN [C] float NOT NULL

Oracle:
ALTER TABLE "Table1" MODIFY ("NewColumn1" BINARY_DOUBLE NOT NULL, "NewColumn2" BINARY_DOUBLE NOT NULL)
```

2. SQL Server does not support specifying multiple columns to be modified in a single ALTER TABLE statement whereas Oracle does. How can I determine using ODBC APIs whether there is support as such?
3. SQL Server uses `ALTER COLUMN` and Oracle uses `MODIFY`. How can I determine using ODBC APIs what keywords does underlying DBMS need in order to modify a column?

My application uses ODBC APIs to interact with any ODBC compliant database. Therefore I need a generic way to find what is supported.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Double quotes (`"`) are part of ANSI-SQL and are supported in both T-SQL and PL\SQL.

Comment: That said, DON'T use double-quotes in Oracle as it will force your object names to be case sensitive. You will then _always_ have to use double-quotes to reference them. Beyond that, I don't think  you can tell programmatically from the ODBC API as that doesn't evaluate SQL syntax at all; only the database itself does that. You'll have to read the documentation to get correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The ODBC API doesn't evaluate SQL syntax. It is only a bridge to the Oracle client, which provides communication to the actual database, which could be any of several versions. Only the database evaluates SQL syntax. As far as I know there is no programmatic way to extract that through an API; you will have to read the version specific documentation and code your application accordingly.